# Somewhat challenging binomial identity

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

> The  binomial identity  valid  for positive  integer  values $n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{n}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-16)^k}{k(n+k)}\binom{n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-2k}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   is somewhat difficult to  prove.  I'm trying to  show (1) using generating functions, but  wasn't successful so far. So, I'm kindly asking for support.

Some information around the problem:

- We can write $\frac{n}{k(n+k)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{n+k}$ which might help to split the left-hand side into simpler sums.
- If we set $a_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}z^k$ we have
  \begin{align*}
  a_n(z)+a_{n-1}(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2n}{n+k}\binom{n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}z^k\\
  &=2\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\binom{n+k}{2k}-\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+k-1}{2k-1}\right)\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}z^k
  \end{align*}
  which could be useful when  we try to write (1) as telescoping  sum.
- We have a representation of reciprocal binomial coefficients via the *[Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)*:

\begin{align*}
\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}&=(2k+1)\int_0^1z^k(1-z)^{k}\,dz\\
&=(2k+1)\int_0^1z^k\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}(-z)^r\,dz\\
&=(2k+1)\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}(-1)^r\int_0^1z^{k+r}\,dz\\
&=(2k+1)\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{k+r+1}\\
&=(2k+1)\sum_{r=0}^k\binom{k}{r}\frac{(-1)^{k-r}}{2k+1-r}
\end{align*}
  which could be useful to  transform (1) into a double sum, exchange  the  sums  and try to apply some telescoping.

- We also have the generating function of associated Legendre polynomials (see e.g. *[Binomial identities](https://www.amazon.com/-/de/gp/product/0471722758)* by J. Riordan):
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{2k}z^k\right)y^n=\frac{1-y}{1-(2+z)y+y^2}
  \end{align*}

Regrettably, despite this info I wasn't able to show (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We write le LHS term as
$$
\eqalign{
  & L(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n
  {{n \over 4}{{\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k\left( {n + k} \right)}}
 \left( \matrix{  n + k \cr   2k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  2k \cr  k \cr}  \right)^{\, - \,1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {{n \over 4}{{\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k\left( {n + k} \right)}}
 \left( \matrix{  n + k \cr   n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  2k \cr   k \cr}  \right)^{\, - \,1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} { - {{4n\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {n + k + 1} \right)}}
 \left( \matrix{  n + k + 1 \cr   n - k - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  2k + 2 \cr   k + 1 \cr}  \right)^{\, - \,1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {T(k,n)}  \cr} 
$$
so to get rid of the upper bound in the sum.

Then we reshape $T(k,n)$ so to render it more manageable
by making use of the gamma duplication formula
$$
\eqalign{
  & T(k,n) =   \cr 
  &  = {{ - \,4n\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {n + k + 1} \right)}}
 \left( \matrix{  n + k + 1 \cr   n - k - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{  2k + 2 \cr  k + 1 \cr}  \right)^{\, - \,1}
 \quad \left| {\,0 \le k \le n - 1} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \,4n{{\Gamma \left( {n + 2 + k} \right)} \over {\left( {n + 1 + k} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)\Gamma \left( {2k + 3} \right)}}
 {{\Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,2} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {2k + 3} \right)}}\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \,4n{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)}}
 {{\Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {2k + 3} \right)^{\,2} }}\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \,4n{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)}}
 {{\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,2} \Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)}
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 3/2} \right)^{\,2} \Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,2} }}{{\left( { - 16} \right)^{\,k} } \over {4^{\,2\,k + 1} }} =   \cr 
  &  =  - \,n{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)}}
 {{\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,2} \Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 3/2} \right)^{\,2} \Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)}}
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  =  - n^{\,2} {{{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)}}}
  \over {{{\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( n \right)}}}}{1 \over {{{\Gamma \left( {k + 3/2} \right)}
  \over {\Gamma \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,2} }}^{\,2} }}{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - n^{\,2} {{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {n^{\,\overline {\, - \,k\,} } }}
 {1 \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}
 {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - n^{\,2} {{\left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
  \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} }
  \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - n^{\,2} {{\left( { - n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
  \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } n^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }
  \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{1 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}} \cr} 
$$

where the single steps should result quite clear.

We do not attempt to go through the Hypergeometric at this point,  which looks complicate.
Instead we go and take the Forward Difference in $n$
$$
\Delta _{\,n} L(n) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\Delta _{\,n} T(k,n)} 
$$
taking advantage of not having the upper bound.

Now
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,n} \left( {\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } n^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - n - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} }  - \left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } n^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - n - 1} \right)\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + k + 1} \right)
 - \left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( { - n + k} \right)n\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \left( {2n + 1} \right)\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  \cr} 
$$
which provides a $(k+1)$ factor, wishfully expected from the Rising Factorials to cancel the disturbing one in the previous derivation

Therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,n} L(n) =  - \left( {2n + 1} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } 1^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }
 \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{1 \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \left( {2n + 1} \right){}_3F_{\,2} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   { - n,\;1,\;n + 1}  \cr 
   {3/2,3/2}  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;1} \right) \cr} 
$$
and we are lucky enough that the factors allow to apply the Saalschütz's theorem
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,n} L(n) =  - \left( {2n + 1} \right){{\left( {3/2 - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } \left( {3/2 - n - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }
 \over {\left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } \left( {3/2 - 1 - n - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  =  - \left( {2n + 1} \right){{\left( {1/2} \right)\left( { - 1/2} \right)} \over {\left( {1/2 + n} \right)\left( { - n - 1/2} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( { - 2n - 1} \right)}} \cr} 
$$

In conclusion, indicating with $R(n)$ the RHS of the identity to demonstrate, we have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  L(0) = R(0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \Delta _{\,n} L(n) = \Delta _{\,n} R(n) =  - {1 \over {\left( {2n + 1} \right)}} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

and **the thesis is proved**

Comment: Very nice approach. I'll go through into more detail soon. Many thanks for your contribution (+1).

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: always glad to return a little help for the lot that I learnt from your answers on this site

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** There is an interesting integral representation of (1),  namely

\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-16)^k}{k(n+k)}\binom{n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}
\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(2nz)-1}{\sin z}\,dz
=}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-2k}
\end{align*}

The validity of this equality-chain is shown in this *[MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560625)*.

Comment: interesting connection, Markus, thanks for presenting it

Comment: @GCab: You're welcome. Thanks for the credit. :-)